# How to run python script forever EC2?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

Problem is when I run a script like:

```
python scripy.py
```

Then when I close the terminal the process is killed.

How to run script forever under Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS?

I have created a service in `/etc/init/publisher.conf` like this:

```
description "Publisher"
author "alissada@gmail.com.com"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]

env AN_ENVIRONMENTAL_VARIABLE=i-want-to-set

respawn

exec /var/www/__init__.py
```

When I tried to run this service:

```
service publisher start
```

I get an error:

> Failed to start publisher.service: Unit publisher.service not found.

Why?

Comment: If you don't mind to install other lib, [pm2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) is a friendly process management tool. FYI.

Comment: It uses Node.js, I want to do that using OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the 'screen' command to start detachable session (apt-get install screen if you don't have it). 'screen' creates what looks like a normal terminal, but you can detach from it (ctrl+a then d I think is the incantation). You can then logout, and whatever you started in the screen session will keep running.

Upon your later return, you can type screen --reattach (I think, you'll have to read the man page) to return to the session you abandoned earlier.